# SymPy express variable in terms of another

Tags: python, sympy

I am using SymPy lib for Python.
I have two sympy symbols and expression that binds them:

```
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
expr = 2 * x - 7 * y
```

How can i express 'y' in terms of 'x', i.e get the equality:

```
y = (2/7) * x
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment, you actually want to solve `expr == 0`, so just do so: `solve(expr, y)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how you can express this equation in terms of `x`:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: x, y = symbols('x, y')

In [3]: expr = 2*x - 7*y

In [4]: solve(expr, y)
Out[4]: [2*x/7]
```

This works because if the solve() function is presented with something that is not a full equation, it assumes that the provided expression is equal to zero. In other words, writing

```
expr = 2*x - 7*y
```

above is equivalent to writing

```
expr = Eq(2*x - 7*y, 0)
```

which would tell SymPy that

```
2x - 7y = 0.
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the first result that shows up in Google search, I'll provide an alternative approach, even though it's not a direct answer to the question.

As the other answer pointed out, if you have **two independent symbols and an equation** relating them, you can use `expr.solve` to express one of them in terms of the other:

```py
x, y = symbols('x y')
expr = 2*x - 7*y

y = solve(expr, y)[0]
y # outputs 2*x/7
```

But sometimes it occurs that you only have **only one independent symbol `x`** and the other symbol `y` is expressed in terms of `x`, and you want to reverse the dependence – **make `y` the independent symbol**.

```
# what we have
y = symbols('y')
x = 7*y/2

# what we want
x = symbols('x')
y = ???
```

That's where this simple utility function comes in handy. It lets you express `a` in terms of `b`.

```py
def express(a, b, name):
    sym = symbols(name)
    sol = solve(a-sym, b)
    assert len(sol) == 1
    return (sym, sol[0])
```

The first argument `a` is the dependent variable that we want to express in terms of the free variable `b`. The third argument `name` is the name we will give to `a` (it was just an unnamed expression until now).

Example usage:

```py
y = symbols('y')
x = 7*y/2

x, y = express(x, y, 'x')
y # outputs 2*x/7
```