# Can Sympy identify functions in expressions, if fuctions are defined?

Tags: python, function, sympy, symbolic-math

I've seen that Sympy has a `sympy.Function` feature, but can't find an answer to the following in the documentation.

Is it possible to find custom functions in expressions and use the function definition to simplify them.

As a very simple example, I define the function: `f(x) = 2 * exp(x)`.

Now let's say I have some Sympy expression: `6 * exp(y + z)`

Is it possible to tell Sympy to simplify this expression to give a result in terms of the function `f`.... i.e. so the output from Sympy is: `3 * f(x)`.

I've found that using `.subs()` works for simple substitution of variables, but this doesn't seem to work for functions that contain symbols as arguments, as above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is not supported by Sympy at the moment (see for instance this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678621/how-to-rewrite-an-expression-in-terms-of-an-other-expression-in-sympy)). Nevertheless, something very close can be done with this code:

```
from sympy import symbols, exp

x, f = symbols('x, f')
expr = 6 * exp(x)
f_func = 2 * exp(x)

print(expr.subs({f_func: f}))
# 3 * f
```

In the above code I have assumed that the expression you wanted to simplify (`expr` in the code) was a function of *x*.

Comment: Thanks. Your code suggestion works but this requires the function to be defined in terms of already known arguments... i.e. Sympy couldn't see 2 * exp(y) and change it to f, unless you explicitly define f as  being equal to 2 * exp(y) in an ealier line. 

Let's hope this is an added feature in the future. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What you want (use the variable `y` without explicitly declaring that the function depends on it) is not possible in sympy, and as far as I know, will never be. You need to declare explicitly the symbols to avoid namespace collisions and related issues. It would be my bet that this is a good as you can get, but I might be wrong. Anyway, I hope the answer helped you. Open to discuss if you want.